# Gedit isn't picking up new plugins

Tags: gedit, plugins

Hi I have tried to install this plugin for gedit by copying the files `auto_completion.gedit-plugin auto_completion.py` to `/usr/share/gedit-2/plugins/autocomplete` however when i restart gedit and go to edit -> preferences this plugin is not listed.

Am I missing a step? Is there a way to tell gedit to look for new plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer found on ubuntu forums here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=710623

`.gnome2/gedit/plugins/` is the right directory (or `/usr/lib/gedit-2/plugins/` if you want them installed systemwide).

Your plugin should have a `.gedit-plugin` file and a .py file or a folder containing .py files with maybe a glade file. the .gedit-plugin must be in the root of the plugins directory (e g: `.gnome2/gedit/plugins/`).

If it still doesn't work try to run gedit from a terminal and look at the output, you may find some useful debug info.